# How to float an img left of text when the text is before it in the markup?

Tags: css, image, css-float

I don't even know if this is possible. I'm trying to make image float left to the text (or text right to the image). I need content to be above image, as with a CSS query, for mobile devices, I'd like to remove formatting and have text remain above image.

https://jsfiddle.net/as1wj9sp/

I tried fixed positioning, but then the image doesn't comply to the rest of the layout.

```css
* {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 list-style-type: none;
 font: 1em/1em Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#content {
 margin: auto;
 background: #FCC;
 padding: 10px;
}
#index {
 background: #063;
 padding: 2px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#index h1 {
 float: right;
}
#index img {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 max-width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div id="index"><h1>The Right Ingredients At The Real Dose asdadasda ad ad as dasdas as das das das dasdas dd asd asdsadasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdas dad asd as</h1>
    <img src="img/image.jpg" alt="test" width="200" height="200" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what the actual issue is here. Why does the image need to float? Ar eyou using media queries at all?

Comment: i will use queries later, but for this web version, i'd like to float the image left and text right. And no it doesn't have to float, I just don't know how else to do it. I just want an easy way later when i change queries for mobile and remove formatting leaving text above image and not below.

Answer (score 2):

I'd change both elements to be `display: block` and then you'll probably need a *width* of the elements, say 50% each for simplicity.

Finalize this concept using a @media-query for mobile devices.

Something like this:

```
    #index h1 {
        float: right;
        display: block;
        width: 60%;
    }
    #index img {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 40%;
    }

/* Or whatever max-width you want */
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        #index h1,
        #index img {
            float: left;
            width: auto;
        }
    }
```

Comment: geez why i didn't realize to put widths to  both elements. Thanx man. this also seems browser compatible.

Answer (score 1):

This answer doesn't use floats, *but* it does achieve what you are trying to do. If you don't need to support old browsers with this, you can use `display: flex;` and `order`. It works in all modern browsers.

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/as1wj9sp/4/)

```css
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    font: 1em/1em Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#content {
    margin: auto;
    background: #FCC;
    padding: 10px;
}
#index {
    background: #063;
    padding: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
}
#index h1 {
    order: 2;
    -webkit-order: 2;
}
#index img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 90%;
    order: 1;
    -webkit-order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div id="index">
        <h1>The Right Ingredients At The Real Dose asdadasda ad ad as dasdas as das das das dasdas dd asd asdsadasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdas dad asd as</h1>
        <img src="img/image.jpg" alt="test" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The `-webkit-` prefixes are for Safari.

Comment: Tyler, thanx, this is looks great. I don't really look into old browser for now, maybe will adjust later based on user browsers. This is what i needed.